# Nodejs undefined var when separate code in models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fs, mongoose-schema

I'm writting my first nodejs app, and i'm getting an error when i move a piece of code to an external js file. the code i'm trying to move is a mongodb schema declaration:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//--------------------users ------------
var usersSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String, 
    phoneNumber: String, 
    BirthDate: Date, 
    loginpwd:String
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);
```

I'm using filesystem module to load the external file:

```
fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/models').forEach(function(filename){
    if (~filename.indexOf('.js')) 
        require(__dirname+'/models/'+ filename);
    console.log(filename+" added");
});
```

the following block does not work well when I separate the code, throwing an "undefined UserModel" error:

```
var userData = new UserModel({email : req.body.edtEmail,
                                        name: req.body.edtName,
                                        phoneNumber: req.body.edtPhoneNumber,
                                        BirthDate: req.body.edtBirthDate,
                                        loginpwd: req.body.edtSenha});
// save user data to database
userData.save(function(err, record){
   if(err) throw err;

    // session setting
    req.session.userEmail = req.body.edtEmail;
    req.session.name = req.body.edtName;
    req.session.phoneNumber = req.body.edtPhoneNumber;
    req.session.birthDate = req.body.edtBirthDate;
    req.session.userId = record._id;
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

the following code works well in both inline code or "in file" code:

```
app.get('/users/json', function(req, res){
    mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users){
        res.send(users);
    });
 });
```

Am I doing something wrong when load external file ? or missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a build in system in nodeJs to load files.

I am not really sure what you want to do but in nodejs you would do something like this

```
//Lets say this file is called UserModel.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//-------------------- rest of you code ------------


var UserModel = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);
module.exports = UserModel; //this is important
```

Than in a another file you could just load this

```
var UserModel = require('UserModel'); 
var bob = new UserModel({ ....
```

so you can work with your UserModel. Read maybe the docs about require

Comment: It works using var userData = new UserModel.userModel. so i changed exported alias to user to make it more readable. Code was changed to "var userData = new UserModel.user({... "   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also can use like:

in your schema file: (say directory "*models/userModel.js*")

```
...
mongoose.model('UserModel', usersSchema);
```

in controller or other file where you want to use: (say directory "*controller/userController.js*")

```
require('../models/userModel');// load user model
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel'),

var userData = new UserModel({email : req.body.edtEmail, //rest of code...});

userData.save(function(err, record){ //rest of code ...
```

and can use for route like: (follow like as controller)

```
app.get('/users/json', function(req, res){
    UserModel.find(function(err, users){
        res.send(users);
    });
 });
```